# correctly write in javascript a value received from a bean

Tags: javascript

I need to pass a value from a bean into a JavaScript part of a HTML page

```
 <script language="javascript" for="obj" event="ControlInitialized>

        obj.URL = #{myBean.ObjectURL};

 </script>
```

where #{myBean.ObjectURL} is :

```
http://localhost:8080/project/descript.xsd
```

Comment: Wrap `#{myBean.ObjectURL}` in quotes: `objURL = '#{myBean.ObjectURL}';`

Comment: you have a double quote at the end of your script  <script language="javascript" ">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always, *always* look at the generated output.

```
obj.URL = http://localhost:8080/project/descript.xsd;
```

Notice anything missing?

```
obj.URL = "http://localhost:8080/project/descript.xsd";
```

Comment: I did this but if I put double quotes, firbug tells me: obj.URL is undefined

Comment: @stackSaru I mis-read your code when typing, didn't see the `.`

Comment: sorry, I over simplified but I finally wrote something closer to reality

Comment: your answer was right, the bug was vicious and came from elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

It must be a string:

```
<script language="javascript" ">
    objURL = "#{myBean.ObjectURL}";
</script>
```

Comment: sorry, it was a typo mistake but in my code, it is correct

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script language="javascript" >   //Remove the extra quote

        obj.URL = "#{myBean.ObjectURL}";  // Put it in quotes

 </script>
```